# Primefaces lazytable search without filtering or sorting

Tags: jsf, search, primefaces

How i can scroll to some page/row in lazytable in one load method?

I have table with 6 milion records and some records deleting and inserting every 1 sec +-.

I need search one record in table and see some surroundings in lazytable.

How i can change first in method load() if i am in this method? Or some any thing else idea how to scroll in all data to my line?

Thanks and sorry for my easy english,
Venca.

Comment: how do you know where you need to be

Comment: select count(*) from table where key <= :key_findedrecord